# Measuring current consumption of evaluation board

Tags: usb, current-measurement, multimeter

I have an evaluation board and I wanted to measure the current consumed by this device. I usually power it off a USB port so I was thinking of getting one of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013FANC9W). There is a two pin jumper on the board that allows use of power from the USB port. Its closed (connected) so that it can power off of the USB port. What is the right way of hooking up a multimeter between these two pins in order to measure the current consumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the right way of hooking up a multimeter between these two pins in order to measure the current consumed?

Just take the jumper off and connect one lead of your multimeter to each pin.

Holding the probes there will probably be difficult, so if I were you I'd find a way to connect them to your multimeter with some jumper wires.

Comment: And don't forget to take the meter off the current mode when you are done.